# Color not filling entire div + padding glitch

Tags: html, css, visual-glitch

```css
#header {
  background-color: #55ff00;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
      <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

The background color fills from the text down to the bottom border; nothing *above* the text. How can I make the background color extend above the text?

There is one way I found that uses this weird glitch. I added `padding: 1px` to the CSS and the background color then extended all the way up like I wanted, but I don't think the code should have done that. I experimented more and found that it only works when the padding is above `0.01953124912688509844105px`.

This was on Visual Studio Code. I replicated it on repl.it and found a different result: `0.015624999534338px` (these are not the exact numbers, it keeps going).

I looked it up and found something relating to this error: https://codepen.io/mikemadman/pen/XRdMZP

Can anyone explain this glitch? And is there a normal way to extend the color upward without using a full border?

Comment: Just a note for next time: When a bug only occurs in specific browsers, it's useful to list the browser names, versions, and OS in the question. Or, if you only tested something in one browser, giving the information for that browser.

Answer (score 0):

Every time your website has a default padding and margin. So you have to remove that padding and margin. I hope my answer is helpful to you. You can read more about that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#header {
  background-color: #55ff00;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
      <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Reset default browser padding and margin with:

```
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

2.Give your elements padding or margin where you need it:

```
#header {
  padding: 15px 30px;
}
```

**Check out the demo below:**

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#header {
  background-color: #55ff00;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
      <h1>Text</h1>
</div>
```